# Accessing shared folder using wifi

Tags: 8.0, file-transfer

Is there a built in way to access a shared folder on a PC / laptop from a windows phone using wifi?

If there is no built in way to do it, is there an app that can do this? Maybe something like this [FileBrowser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) app (FileBrowser is not a winphone app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [ShareFolder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/sharefolder/e2b9c82e-eaa1-4a3b-9d4a-8a2933a8bdb4) app that enable browsing and accessing files on my windows machine. As far as I know this is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

No. There isn't any built in way to browse files on computer. But you can do the opposite, accessing files from the phone in the computer via data cable.

Comment: I use SkyDrive to get things from the phone (over wifi) and then back to a PC (again over wifi.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your are using  windows 7 & above. If your network card supports you can setup an ad-hoc connection or use the wifi router [See here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/simple-windows-7-file-sharing-step-by-step-procedure/)

These are some of the basic steps to host a directory using IIS and access it over WiFi LAN, you can google more about it.

1. Search for IIS (start-->search IIS)
2. GoTo "Default WebSite" the one hosted on port 80 (default http port)
3. Right Click --> manage sites -->Advance settings
4. Change the Physical path to any folder that you want to host
5. Then GoTo Directory Browsing and enable it
6. Now get the IP address assigned to your PC (by the router generally it will be 192.168.1.2)
7. Connect to the same wifi address using your phone once connected open "192.168.1.2" or your pc IP address

If everything goes well you can see all the files from your PC in your mobile, and ifthe browser supports you can play videos also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared folder on the phone and can access them from your pc though. This app can do that - 
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=103e9262-cb78-4513-a79d-f4007771b71f

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an option in **PC Remote**, where you can access your PC's hard drive over wifi. You must install **PC Remote Server** on you computer and set the password.